# Pandas replace not working (ERROR: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame)

Tags: python, pandas

Couldn't find an answer that worked from similar questions.

I have a dataframe(data), which I created a new dataframe(clothes) from.

Code:

```
clothes = data[['title_orig', 'retail_price','units_sold']].copy()
```

Output:

```
**title_orig**                **retail_price**     **units_sold**
summer vintage flamingo top              14                 100
women's casual sleeveless top            22               20000
cool t shirt for women                   43                 100
spring and summer women top               8                5000
```

**When I tried replacing "women" and "women's" with '' (blank), it doesn't work. First I was getting this message "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame", but now I get zero error and "women" and "women's" is still there.**

```
clothes['title_orig'] = clothes['title_orig'].replace('women', '')
```

Comment: you need to use str `clothes['title_orig'] = clothes['title_orig'].str.replace('women', '')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix that turn `regex = True`

```
clothes['title_orig'] = clothes['title_orig'].replace({'women' : ''}, regex = True)
```